# Primeng multiple row selection on checkbox and single selection on clicking the row

Tags: angular, primeng

Hello I need to have multiple selection via click on checkbox and single selection after click on the row. Have you any idea how can I join this on the same table?

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/table/selection

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onRowSelect` to remove everything else from the selection but the clicked item.

Your p-table definition will be like:

```html
<p-table selectionMode="multiple" [(selection)]="selectedItems" (onRowSelect)="onRowSelect($event) ...> ... </p-table>
```

and your function

```js
onRowSelect(event) {
  this.selectedItems = [event.data];
}
```

So that checkboxes use the default primeng behaviour, while row clicking deselects everything else.

Comment: `onRowSelect(event) { this.selectedItems = null; this.selectedItems = [event.data]; }`

Something like this? This is not working. How can I deselects everything else?